# Loop over subset of variables in JuMP constraint

Tags: loops, constraints, julia, julia-jump, network-flow

I am trying to implement an arc-flow problem where I have a set of arcs in an array. Each arc is a custom data structure composed of from/to nodes. I want to add a constraint where I only include the arcs that go from a specific node (1), something like:

```
@constraint(m, sum(x[a] for a in arcs; a.from==1) == 1)
```

This does not work. What is the best approach to deal with this? Is there a way to do it without precomputing all outgoing arcs from each node first? If so, is there a way to add additional conditions?
Thanks in advance

Bernardo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm guessing that the syntax you're looking for is

```
@constraint(m, sum(x[a] for a in arcs if a.from==1) == 1)
```

This follows from the standard Julia syntax for [generator expressions](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/manual/arrays/#Generator-Expressions).

However, the expression is just as inefficient as it would be in plain Julia because it loops through all arcs. If it this looping becomes a bottleneck, you'll need to reformulate the expression in another way, e.g., by precomputing the outgoing arcs from each node.

Comment: Yes, that solved my issue. I forgot to mention that I'm not worried about looping over all arcs when building the constraint.

Answer (score 1):

You need to redefine your `x` to be an [adjacency matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adjacency_matrix), that is a square matrix that has `1` (or edge weight) where there is an arc between a pair of nodes and `0` otherwise.

Assuming that the set of vertices you are considering is `N`  (e.g. `N = 1:10` for `10` vertices) your constraint can now look like this:

```
@constraint(m, arcConstraint[n in N], sum(x[n,k] for k ∈ N) == 1 )
```

Note that `arcConstraint` is just the constraint name so you can reference it later.

The `sum` can be also written as  `sum(x[n,:])` if you actually know that you go through the entire column (depends on your exact scenario).

Comment: Wouldn't this involve the creation of NxN variables? In my case, the amount of arcs in the problem is significantly lower than NxN and I want to avoid having so many variables (just one per arc).

Comment: You cannot have conditional instructions in a JuMP model (since the solvers do not support it). If your goal is to select arcs for a graph having size N, naturally you have NxN variables (or half of that for an undirected graph). If your N is large than depending on some specific characteristics of your problem you could try to re-structure it but than this is a mathematic modelling rather than Julia JuMP issue